# filter a `git grep` search on more than one pattern

Tags: git, grep

to filter a `git grep` search on one file pattern I use this::

```
$ git grep xyz -- '*.py'
```

How can I search on more than one pattern ?

This did not work:

```
 $ git grep xyz -- '*.{py,yml}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested:

```
git grep xyz -- *.py *.yml
```

That bash expansion does the right thing and `git grep` applies to the expected set of files.